# How could i handle the exceptions in the below code sample.?

Tags: java, exception

Below is the method that might return IndexOutofBounds exception. I want to handle the exceptions using try and catch instead of throws. Please help me.

I have tried try and catch but where should i use the return statement , is it after try or catch.

```
**@RequestMapping(value = "/hospitals/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Hospital getHospital(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        Hospital hospital = this.hospitalService.getHospital(id);

        return hospital;
    }**
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Is this Java? If so, tag your question with [tag:java]. Have you tried using `try` and `catch`? If not, why not? If so, what did you try, and what _specifically_ do you need help with? Please read [ask], and see also [mcve] for how to provide a good code example that clearly illustrates your question.

Comment: Updated the question properly. Have tried try and catch within method but where should i use return statement.?

Comment: Depends on how you are handling the exception. For example, maybe you want `Hospital hospital = null; try { hospital = this.hospitalService.getHospital(id); } catch (...) {  /* report error somehow */ } return hospital;`. Or maybe you want `try { return this.hospitalService.getHospital(id); } catch (...) {  return this.defaultHospital; }` Or maybe something else. There's not enough information in your question to know. You have to return _something_, or throw an exception. You can put one or more `return` statements, as needed. The compiler won't let you forget one.

Comment: The approach in general is probably already bad. Why cant you check the size before instead of invoking the exception in the first place? You should never use exceptions/try-catch for **regular** control flow.

Comment: Thanks @PeterDuniho , i will use multiple return statements.

Answer (score -1):

As per [Peter Duniho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3538012/peter-duniho) comment...

```
public Hospital getHospital(int id) {
    Hospital hospital = null;
    try {
        hospital = hospitalService.getHospital(id);
    }
    catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hospital;
}
```

If the line inside the `try` throws an exception, then the stack trace will be written to the console and the method will return null.

If the line inside the `try` does not throw an exception, the method will return the `Hospital` object with the given `id`.